# access username in the text field of form in yii app (using yii user management module)

Tags: php, yii

I am using User_Management_Module_0.4 in my yii app.

I have a model business to store users business in table.

table having fields username( I need same user name which is stored in users table which is of user management module)

in my _form.php I try to get the username of loged in user but its not working.

whats wrong in my code??
please tell me
_form.php

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'shops-form',
'type'=>'horizontal',
'enableClientValidation'=>false,
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>




<div class="row">

    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'name',$model->getUserOptions()); ?>
</div>
```

business.php (model)

```
public function getUserOptions()
{$username = Yii::t("UserModule.user", "username");

    //$uname =Yii::app()->user->username;

    return $username;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an ActiveForm. If you look at the documentation at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#textField-detail,
you can see that the third param are the html options.

If you want the username of logged user into the field, you can set the attribute `$model->name = Yii::app()->user->name` or your custom function `$model->name = $model->getUserOptions();` into your controller that renders the view with the form.

Comment: <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'name',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'value'=>Yii::app()->user->name,'disabled'=>'disabled')); ?> It workes fine. Thank you..

Comment: same way how can i get the email of that user in the emailtext field??? i tried as <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'email',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'value'=>Yii::app()->user->data,'disabled'=>'disabled')); ?> its not working

Comment: In this case, you should perform a query on the database, you don't have that information in Cwebuser object. My suggestion is to create a  CFormModel with the related fields name, email, etc.. and assign it to the form. [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/it/form.model) you can follow this guide